# Unable to Set page$.layout from within ngOnInit()

Tags: angular, typescript

In my angular PageComponent I'm trying to implement a feature where someone can select a page layout that they want for the page. The page content part of it works, but the problem I'm having is that when someone selects a layout other than the default, it doesn't actually set the layout to the new one.

Here's the component TS code:

```
export class PageComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  public layout: string = "superCentered" || "sidebar" || "pancake" || "holyGrail" || "ramTwo" || "ramFour" || "ramSix" || "lineUp";
  public page$;
  pgSlug;
  static;
  public pageContent;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private dataService: DataService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    if(this.route.snapshot.data['pageContent']) { // This block determines if there is static page content associated with the route and acts accordingly as seen below
      this.layout = this.route.snapshot.data['layout']; // Sets the layout to the statically determined route
      this.pageContent = this.route.snapshot.data['pageContent']; // Sets the page content to the statically coded page content
    } else { // This block is executed if there is no static page content, meaning the DB needs to fetch said data
      this.page$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe( // This block sets the cached page data to the data gotten from the service below
        switchMap(params => {
          const pageName = params.get('page'); // Sets variable for page name
          this.pgSlug = pageName; // Sets slug for internal use
          setTimeout( ()=> this.layout = this.page$.layout); // This is where the layout would be set, but this doesn't work- this is because the page$.layout doesn't exist- not sure why
          return this.dataService.getPage(pageName); // Returns the data for the page$
        })
      );
    }
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    /* haven't implemented code here yet */
  }
}
```

The challenge I'm having here is that the page$ needs to have a value, which happens through the `return this.dataService.getPage(pageName);` statement. The problem is that I can't add more code after that, so I tried a `setTimeout( ()=> this.layout = this.page$.layout);`, but that hasn't worked for me so I'm lost for what to do to get this feature working.

Comment: what do you mean you can't add more code after that? can't you just use another rxjs operator in the pipe?

Comment: Which pipe would I use? Because after the `return` I wasn't able to add another line (theoretically I *could* add it, but it wouldn't do anything)

Comment: wait.... I just noticed something you are creating an observable but are not subscribing to it, so your code is actually not doing anything there. 
substitute the line with just `);` with `).subscribe( result =>  { /* ... your code here, when you update your layout field ... */ })` that should do it

Comment: I just gave that a go but now I get this in the browser console: `ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'`

Comment: For reference, in the .subscribe code I put this: `console.warn(result); this.layout = result.layout;` and the result object is what it is supposed to be (`{layout: "superCentered", pageContent: "<h1>REE</h1>"}`) (Just used 'ree' as a placeholder- not real content)

Comment: So after some further toying around with the code, the problem is the fact that there's a subscription occurring because if I comment out the subscription, it works fine (with the exception of setting the layout) but if I add the subscription back, it doesn't work and I get multiple errors thrown.

Comment: ok I am super in for helping out, but I think I need to see the thing run by myself otherwise it's getting too convoluted, is the code up on github or something by any chance? or if it's not could yo create a project here on https://stackblitz.com/ or https://codesandbox.io/ please?

Comment: Unfortunately it is part of a work project and my timebox was just ended so unfortunately I need to work on some other stuff in my sprint but after I am done working for today I'll see if I can make a minimum viable reproduction on stackblitz.

Comment: I see, I am sorry I could not help (for now at least) if you'll be able to make a stackblitz reproduction that'd we awesome and I will definitely have a look :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand the problem correctly but I think that the `tap` operator is what you're looking for:

```
 this.page$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe( // This block sets the cached page data to the data gotten from the service below
    switchMap(params => {
      const pageName = params.get('page'); // Sets variable for page name
      this.pgSlug = pageName; // Sets slug for internal use
      return this.dataService.getPage(pageName); // Returns the data for the page$
    }), 
    tap(page => this.layout = page.layout)
  );
```